# jQuery: «.children» vs «.find» + «.live»

Tags: jquery, find, live, children

Here are there pieces of code:

HTML:

```
<div class="thematicHeaderBox group">
 <h3 class="thematicHeader group">SMTH</h3>
 <button class="activatedUsual" style="float: right; ">on</button>
</div>
```

JS, do NOT work:

```
attachEvents(
 $(".thematicHeaderBox").children(".activatedUsual"),
 self.elem.box.thematic.settings.event
);
```

JS, WORKS:

```
attachEvents(
 $(".thematicHeaderBox").find(".activatedUsual"),
 self.elem.box.thematic.settings.event
);
```

attachEvents func:

```
function attachEvents (elems, data) {

    for(var p in data){
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(p)){
            elems.live(
                data[p].name,
                data[p].callback
            );
        }
    }
}
```

data is an array of objects events name and callbacks to use.

Question is why only second variant works correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: Question is why only second variant works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The `.children()` method allows us to search through the **immediate children** of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Immediate children means one level of hierarchy. In your case, `.activatedUsual` is not the immediate child of '.thematicHeaderBox'.

Comment: A child element is by definition immediately beneath another element in the hierarchy...

Comment: Exactly. But he's looking for a child of child of something using `.children()`. I just explain the definition.

Comment: Logging

$(".thematicHeaderBox").find(".onBtnType1, .offBtnType1"));
and
$(".thematicHeaderBox").children(".onBtnType1, .offBtnType1"))

gives me the same list of elements.

Comment: They are both at the first level of `.thematicHeaderBox` children hierarchy. right?